# Minecraft Forge - Place block onItemUse

Tags: minecraft, minecraft-forge

I'm trying to make my custom item place water when used:

```
public class Beaker extends Item implements IHasModel {
  public Beaker(String name, CreativeTabs tab, int maxStackSize) {
    setUnlocalizedName(name);
    setRegistryName(name);
    setCreativeTab(tab);
    setMaxStackSize(maxStackSize);

    ItemInit.ITEMS.add(this);
  }

  @Override
  public void registerModels() {
    Main.proxy.registerItemRenderer(this, 0, "inventory");
  }

  @Override
  public EnumActionResult onItemUse(EntityPlayer player, World worldIn, BlockPos pos, EnumHand hand, EnumFacing facing, float hitX, float hitY, float hitZ) {
    BlockPos clickedBlock = new BlockPos(hitX, hitY, hitZ);
    worldIn.setBlockState(clickedBlock, Blocks.WATER.getDefaultState());
    return EnumActionResult.SUCCESS;
  }
}
```

However, when I right click, the item gets used (animation plays) but the water is not placed, I'm using Minecraft 1.12.2 and Forge 14.23.2.2613.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hitX` `hitY` and `hitZ` have no relation to the world location where the action was performed. They are partial values within the clicked block for performing actions based on *where* the block was clicked (e.g. which button on a number pad).

If we look at `ItemBlockSpecial` (which handles items like Cake, Repeaters, Brewing Stands, and Cauldrons) we find this code:

```
public EnumActionResult onItemUse(EntityPlayer player, World worldIn, BlockPos pos, EnumHand hand, EnumFacing facing, float hitX, float hitY, float hitZ)
{
    IBlockState iblockstate = worldIn.getBlockState(pos);
    Block block = iblockstate.getBlock();

    // snow layer stuff we don't care about
    if (!block.isReplaceable(worldIn, pos))
    {
        pos = pos.offset(facing);
    }
    // placement code
}
```

The important thing to note here is that the `pos` parameter is used directly, while being modified by the `facing` parameter in the event that the block clicked is not replaceable (e.g. Tall Grass is replaceable, Stone is not).

If `ItemBlockSpecial` isn't sufficient for you (i.e. you can't make your item an instance of `ItemBlockSpecial`), then the code it uses to do things probably still will be.

Comment: wouldn't  `canItemEditBlocks()` need to be overriden too to return true?

Comment: I managed to place the water, but it stands static even tho I'm using Blocks.FLOWING_WATER.

Comment: Never mind, just change `EnumActionResult.PASS` to `EnumActionResult.SUCCESS`.

Comment: @Skgland Maybe, I haven't messed with these sorts of items myself.